# Talk to telegram user from node-red

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, node-red, redbot

How to send a message to telegram user from node-red if it's not a reply to a previous message sent by the user?
(I am using telegram bot as a chatbot with users)

Answer (score 0):

The main thing in sending a telegram message from Node-Red is you need a way to capture every user 'Telegram ID'.
There is already a nice tutorial about sending messages [on iotwithus](https://www.iotwithus.com/send-messages-using-telegram-and-node-red/).

The short story is you will need a Function node before Telegram sender node that will contain:

```
msg.payload = {}
msg.payload.chatId = your-id-here
msg.payload.type = ‘message’
msg.payload.content = ‘hello from node-red!’
return msg;
```

Keep in mind to save your users Telegram ID as an integer, not a string, as you can see, we set payload.chatID without the quotes.